# Issues with an elementary proof

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

I'm a very newbie in number theory and I'm having some troubles with the following exercise, because I can't understand the answer given.

This is the exercise:

> Show that if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, then there is a smallest
>   positive integer of the form $a - bk, k \in \Bbb Z$

The answer given is:

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $S = \{n:n \in\mathbb{N} \wedge  n = a - bk, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ Now $S$ is nonempty since $a + b =
 a - b(-1)\in S$. By the well ordering principle, $S$ has a least
 element.

Ok I partly got it.
The answer given considers only the case where $a + b > 0$, with $k < 0$, so that S is non empty.
But why can't we consider also the case where $b>a$ and $k>0$ so that $a+b<0$?

Comment: But what is the proposition you're trying to prove? The Well-Ordering Principle?

Comment: answer  given is ...... Where is the question?

Comment: I guess this is a proof to what's sometimes called as division algorithm (or law?) which basically states that for every $a,b$ integers there is some $k$ such that $a=bk+n$ for $0\le n <a$

Comment: Presumably you are proving the *Division Algorithm*,  i,e. $\,a = bk+ n\,$ for $\,0\le n < a.\ $ That range for the remainder $\,n = a\bmod b\,$ is the normal convention (though one could choose others, e.g. least magnitude). It works fine if $\,b>a\ $

Comment: I suggest, Huseyin78, that you edit your post to include the original question to which you've posted an answer.

Comment: @Vidyanshu Mishra Usually, the question is the part ending with "?", in this case starting with "But why can't we...". While the question may be tricky to locate, the answer is obvious: because $S$ by definition contains only positive numbers. And that's crucial, since positive integers are well-ordered, the set of all (including negative) integers isn't.

Comment: Because $\mathbb Z$ doesn't satisfy the well ordering principle.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I don't know why it hadn't taken the question. Now I've edited it. I'm really sorry about that.

Comment: I've edit it so please, consider to unhold it, if it's clear enough